# Как отсортировать файлы по дате в имени?

Tags: c#

Есть 10 файлов в формате xls. Название у них `dd.mm.yy`. Как отсортировать список     `files` по возрастанию дат? Не совсем понятно как привести имя файла к `DateTime`  и отсортировать их.

```
 var path = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1\DBCommanderNew\bin\Debug";
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(
            path,"*.xls").Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var path = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1\DBCommanderNew\bin\Debug";
var files = Directory
    .GetFiles(path,"*.xls")
    .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x))
    .OrderBy(x => 
        {
            DateTime date;
            return DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "dd.MM.yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date)
                ? date
                : DateTime.MinValue;
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

C# 7:

```
    {
        var path = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1\DBCommanderNew\bin\Debug";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xls")
            .Select(x => Selector(x))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Item2.Date)
            .Select(x => x.Item1)
            .ToList();
    }

    private static (string, DateTime) Selector(string input)
    {
        var file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(input);
        if (DateTime.TryParse(file, out DateTime dateTime))
            return (file, dateTime);

        return (file, DateTime.MinValue);
    }
```

C# 6:

```
    {
        var path = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1\DBCommanderNew\bin\Debug";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xls")
            .Select(x => Selector(x))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Item2.Date)
            .Select(x => x.Item1)
            .ToList();
    }

    private static Tuple<string, DateTime> Selector(string input)
    {
        var file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(input);
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(file , out dt))
            return Tuple.Create(file, dt);
        return Tuple.Create(file, DateTime.MinValue);
    }
```

Comment: Лучше использовать `TryParseExact`.

Comment: А почему не просто `OrderBy(x => Selector(x))` и не заморачиваться с туплами?

Comment: @VladD, хм.. действительно)

Comment: @VladD не могли бы Вы дать ссылку на разъяснения по поводу `Selector` (в идеале на "великом могучем")? Что это такое и как это готовить?!

Comment: @XelaNimed: Так там вроде ж всё просто? Селектор по объекту возвращает значение для сортировки.

Comment: @VladD утро, оказалось, вечера мудренее...